# Select row where all records with similar row meet condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with many records, but for example..

```
ID | USER ID | DATE
1  | 1       | 2014-05-26
2  | 1       | 2015-05-08
3  | 2       | 2014-05-20
```

I am trying to select USER_ID for records whose date is more than 6 months passed, but dont include them if there is another record with same USER_ID who does not meet that criteria. 
So for example, I would want to return only the record with user id 2.

My issue is I can do

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(month, DATE, GETDATE()) > 6
```

but that will still return a record with USER_ID 1. I am sure this is super easy but I have not been able to make progress on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take your statement and take the other away:

```
    WITH UsersWithYoungerDates AS
    (
        SELECT USER_ID
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE DATEDIFF(month, DATE, GETDATE()) <= 6 
    )
    SELECT USER_ID 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(month, DATE, GETDATE()) > 6
    AND USER_ID NOT IN(SELECT USER_ID FROM UsersWithYoungerDates)
```

Comment: Using the WITH clause returned "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon". Not sure what the issue is there.

Comment: Is there a previous statement? Anyway, you should get into the habit of appending a semicolon to _all_ statements, as MS have noted this _might_ be made mandatory in the future. (Perhaps somewhat unlikely, but why take the risk?)

Comment: @user3299574: Just start with a ";" in front of the WITH. And please tick this as accepted, if this solves your prblem, thx

Comment: I had a USE statement. Would that require a ';'?

Comment: Yes, in fact you should put one behind **every** statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, [DATE], GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above will exclude any `USER_ID`s having *at least one* row whose `DATE` is `6` or less than  `6` months old.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88637/1)

If you want to select all fields, then you can use a windowed version of conditional `COUNT` like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(month, [DATE], GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID) AS cnt       
  FROM mytable ) t
WHERE cnt = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88637/3)

or, alternatively, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID 
                        AND DATEDIFF(month, t2.[DATE], GETDATE()) <= 6)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88637/5)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEDIFF( month, DATE, GETDATE()) > 6 AND USER_ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT USER_ID
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE DATEDIFF( month, DATE, GETDATE()) <= 6
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, DATE, GETDATE()) > 6
and USER_ID not in (
    select USER_ID
    from [TABLE]
    where 6 <= datediff(month, date, getdate())
);
```

Note this will filter to *7 months or greater*, not "more than 6 months". DATEDIFF rounds down. You might want to redesign that aspect of your original plan.

Also you probably know this, but `TABLE` is a reserved word, so if it were not just a (misguided :P) placeholder, it would need identifier delimiters.